# Unique numbering for two lines of equations

Tags: align, eqnarray

How can you place the numbering of the equation as in the image? (I have observed that in Cauchy problems, it appears this way)
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: use `amsmath` end write equations in `split environment which is in `equation` environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *many* ways to achieve your formatting objective. The [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package provides several math environments for just this purpose. Which environment to use will depend importantly on how "EQ. 1" and "EQ. 2" are structured. If there's a common alignment point (such as an `=` symbol), a `split` or `aligned` environment should be considered. If no such alignment is needed, a `gathered` environment may be the way to go.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for split and gathered environments
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example
\begin{document} 
\stepcounter{section}    % just for this example

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a &= b+c \\
d &= e+f
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
u = xx + vv \\
xx = yyy + zzzz
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is just what she was looking for.